# Untraceable error when building a SOAP request from a WSDL

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, wsdl, wsit

I have a Java Application in Netbeans 7.3.1 and am using a `wsdl` to create a `SOAP Request`. I am using `Metro` and `WSIT` to sign the request. When I attempt to build / send the request, I receive the following error:

```
    com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException:  name: com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration value: false
```

The full output of the error log is :

```
   Jul 25, 2013 12:13:13 PM com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor sign
   SEVERE: WSS1701: Sign operation failed.
   com.sun.xml.wss.impl.XWSSecurityRuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration value: false
   at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.SignatureProcessor.performRSASign(SignatureProcessor.java:151)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Signature.sign(Signature.java:253)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign(SignatureProcessor.java:127)
   at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.sign(SignatureFilter.java:649)
   at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process(SignatureFilter.java:608)
   at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy(HarnessUtil.java:99)
   at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep(HarnessUtil.java:278)
   at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.processMessagePolicy(SecurityAnnotator.java:194)
   at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.secureMessage(SecurityAnnotator.java:155)
   at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:388)
   at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:323)
   at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:247)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.executeService(Unknown Source)
   at javaapplication7.JavaApplication7.main(JavaApplication7.java:33)

   Caused by: javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration value: false
   at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.setProperty(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:358)
   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.setProperty(MarshallerImpl.java:527)
   at        com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.SignatureProcessor.getMarshaller(SignatureProcessor.java:469)
   at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.SignatureProcessor.performRSASign(SignatureProcessor.java:136)
   ... 22 more
```

All of the classes and line numbers shown in the error log are under the hood classes. I cannot find anything in the error log that connects to my project.

I have found several forums online with information about this error, but none of them have solved my problem. The forums I found can be found [`here`](https://www.java.net//node/685090), [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262781/soap-action-wsdl), and [`here`](http://timepassguys.blogspot.com/2011/12/jaxb-exception-javaxxmlbindpropertyexce.html)

If anyone could point me in the direction of any information or tutorials it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks