# Soap webservice not giving response

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I have been provided by a soap webservice which has a wsdl with soapaction = ""

```
<wsdl:binding name="SimpleSearchRequestSoapBinding" type="impl:SimpleSearchRequest">
<wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="getSearchResults"><wsdlsoap:operation **soapAction=""**/>
<wsdl:input name="getSearchResultsRequest">
<wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getSearchResultsResponse">
<wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Hitting the webservice like this:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(OKMConstants.NAMESPACE, OKMConstants.OPERATION_NAME);        
             request.addProperty("searchParam","faq");

             SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
             soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

             HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(OKMConstants.url);

                         httpTransport.call("", soapEnvelope);        
        //   Object response =  soapEnvelope.getResponse();

             SoapObject result = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
```

But its throwing exception:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:62 in java.io.InputStreamReader@410b9d60)
```

Comment: XML message problem from the looks of it.  Why don't you consider the exception message a clue?

Comment: Is it on the web service(server) side or on client  side? I think its due to the empty soapaction ??

Comment: The service is telling your client that it sent a bad message.

Comment: Still not getting. Thanks for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262781/soap-action-wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass soapAction `null` (it will be set as empty string by ksoap2) or pass empty string with quotes:
`httpTransport.call("\"\"", soapEnvelope);`

Answer (score 0):

httpTransport.call(SOAPACTION,soapEnvelope);

think in this line may be the issue, try using soapAction in call method instead.

Comment: From the wsdl soap action is blank