# Invoking SOAP request from shell command

Tags: shell, unix, soap

I using curl to send a SOAP request to a web service and get the response using shell scripting. please find below the command i am using:-

```
curl  -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:" -d @sample_request.txt -X POST http://someWebServiceURL
```

I am getting an error response which says no SOAPAction header.
PFB the response body part

```
<soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode>Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
<faultstring>WSWS3147E: Error: no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
</soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Any help is appreciated !!

Answer (score 12):

You need to provide the name of the SOAP action. You have:

```
-H "SOAPAction:"
```

Supply the name of the action in there. E.g.

```
-H "SOAPAction: http://my_example/my_action"
```

Get the name of the action from the WSDL if you have one. E.g., see [How do you determine a valid SoapAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128263/how-do-you-determine-a-valid-soapaction).

Comment: Do not forget to quote the URI in the SoapAction header - the spec requires that if it is not null, then it must be double quoted i.e. `SOAPAction: "http://my_example/my_action"`

Answer (score 1):

From the WSDL of the service, you can find the `SoapAction`. And you can find the operation you're trying to invoke and access the WSDL by opening a web browser to the URL of the service.
Using the `curl` to invoke the `SoapAction`, you should specify the `Action` by `"-H"`, such as `-H SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/Execute`.

Comment: is there any other way in bash linux to do this without curl?