# Is there any method to call a web service automatically?

Tags: linux, shell, curl, groovy, soapui

I have a web method `getAllUsers` and I want this method to be called every week. I was thinking to write a script which could call this method and then use `crontab` on the script which is scheduled for every week. I have this web service in the `SOAP UI framework`, so could you let me know how can I call the web service through an script. I am quiet new to this and I have executed the web service manually from the framework but I was looking for a script which could call the web service on running the script. Is there anyway by which I can use CURL to invoke the SOAP web service...Please help...

Comment: Does this post help you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186774/invoking-soap-request-from-shell-command

Comment: I went through the link and I am not sure what exactly the command was doing so I wanted to write a script in a similar way..Could you provide a curl command with the general syntax so that I can use it to call the webservice...

Comment: does the call to the remote web service URL require a POST or a GET?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to call soap ui tests using crontab.

Running functional tests from the command-line is straightforward using the included in soap ui testrunner.bat/.sh script, which takes a number of arguments to control which tests to run, output, for example:

```
sh SmartBear/soapUI-4.5.1/bin/testrunner.sh -s"TestSuite 1" -r -a -fyour_folder/reports your_folder/your_project-soapui-project.xml
```

Where:
`SmartBear/soapUI-4.5.1/bin/testrunner.sh` : path to running script
`-s "TestSuite 1"`: test suite name
`-r` : create summary report in console
`-a` : exporting of all test results in report, not only errors
`-f your_folder/reports` : path to your reports folder
`your_folder/your_project-soapui-project.xml` : path to your soap ui project file

More information here: http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html

And in crontab you just need to start this shell command.

Comment: Why use "-r" from cron?

Comment: It's just an example of available options